# Sci Fi movie involving alien brother and sister (not Witch Mountain) with telekinesis powers

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Can anyone help me with the title of a movie I can recall.  This is what i know:

- Brother and sister (both aliens) with telekinesis powers
- They have an alien mother who dies (I believe she dies while giving birth to them)
- The twins are raised by a female doctor/scientist who experiments on them (board games, etc) to test their knowledge.
- The doctor describes the siblings in the movie as being "slow" maybe with some mental disabilities however, the siblings have special telekinesis powers that they use when she isn't looking.
- In one scene the siblings are asked to arrange a group of blocks but "seem" bewildered.  Once the doctor turns her back, they move the objects telepathically.
- The siblings never speak in the movie.
- They look human.
- At some point, they turn against her and kill her.
- In the closing scene the brother escapes (from this underground place [laboratory?]) and where presumably he will live among humanity. He is seen wearing a hoodie as he walks among humanity.

**Other details**

- Most of the movie takes place somewhere underground
- A group of people with guns go to this underground place to rescue?  the aliens?  Not sure.
- On the way underground the group encounters robots (with heads made of round glass).  The group shoots them down as they make their way downwards.
- In the movie we learn that the female doctor/scientist experiments on these two siblings in this underground place because in other countries she was not allowed this flexibility of experimenting on humans.

The movie is in English. I'm not sure from what country.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *Slapstick of Another Kind* as per the answer to [Movie with brother and sister with latent talents](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128853/movie-with-brother-and-sister-with-latent-talents)?

> Caleb Swain (Jerry Lewis) and his wife Letitia (Madeline Kahn) are called "the most beautiful of all the beautiful people" by the press. However, when Letitia gives birth to twins who are called "monsters", the family doctor, Dr. Frankenstein (John Abbott) informs the parents that the twins won't live more than a few months. The Swains decide to allow the twins to live their short life in a mansion staffed with servants, including Sylvester (Marty Feldman).
>
> Fifteen years later, the twins (also played by Lewis and Kahn) are still alive. They have large heads and appear to be mentally retarded. Their parents, who have not seen them in all those years, receive a visit from the former Chinese ambassador who informs them that their children are geniuses who can solve the world's problems. [...] A series of tests reveal that there is a telepathic connection between the twins, and their intelligence is only functional when they are together. Furthermore, when their heads are touching they reach a level of intelligence that has never been surpassed.
>
> Their parents, fearful that incest may be prevalent, separate the two. They become despondent without each other, and the Chinese ambassador appears again to tell them to seek each other out. Once united, a spaceship appears and reveals that they are really aliens who were sent to Earth to solve all of the planet's problems

### Video clip

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to Scintilla: The Hybrid (2014)?

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2798456/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Could you [edit] your answer to add some details about the movie and particularly how it does (or does not) match the question?  Answers that just provide a link are discouraged because the required information is not all here, and the link may break at some point in the future.